# Sending POJO to Kafka with pre-defined Avro schema in Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

We have a Confluent Schema Registry set up in the cloud that has an Avro schema for the following topics.

- Schema `dummytopic-key` has a single field `id` which is a `string`.
- Schema `dummytopic-value` has a field `name` which is a `string` and a field `score` which is a `double`.

We are now trying to implement a Scala-based producer using Confluent's `kafka-client` and avro serializer `kafka-avro-serializer`. We have our classes defined as follows.

```scala
class DummyKey (val id: java.lang.String)
class DummyValue (val name: java.lang.String, val score: java.lang.Double)
```

Serialization of these classes does not work out of the box, because the classes are not supported Avro types. The problem is that the solutions we find online are either defining an explicit schema for these classes on the producer side, or try to derive the schema by reflection. What we want is a way to pick up the schema from the Schema Registry, and use that schema to serialize our classes.

An illustration of what this should look like

```scala
object MyApp {
  val producerProps = new Properties()
  // Omitted: properties for Kafka bootstrap servers, TLS, key/value Avro serializers, etc.
  // Omitted: declare a schemaRegistryClient

  val dummyKeySerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer(schemaRegistryClient)
  dummyKeySerializer.configure(schemaRegistryConfig, true)
  val dummyValueSerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer(schemaRegistryClient)
  dummyValueSerializer.configure(schemaRegistryConfig, false)

  val producer = new KafkaProducer(producerProps, dummyKeySerializer, dummyValueSerializer)

  val dummyKey = new DummyKey(checkTransaction.transactionid)
  val dummyValue = new DummyValue("test", 0.5)
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord("dummytopic", dummyKey, dummyValue))
}
```

The `producer.send` function complains of an `Unsupported Avro type` because `DummyKey` and `DummyValue` are not instances of `IndexedRecord`. There seem to be two options.

- Is there a way to create an `IndexedRecord` from a POJO, using the schema that is defined in the Schema Registry?
- Is there any other serialization method that loads the schema from the Schema Registry without relying on a locally created schema?

Comment: You should use Maven, or similar build tool to download the schema from the registry prior to compiling your code. Otherwise, use avro4s to convert your classes to Avro objects